# ScrollView scrolls to the same view after using of scrollTo()

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a bunch of view in `ScrollView`. 
Some of them are `TextInputEditText`. 
When an error occurs I use `setError` for particular `TextInputEditText`.
And I have such effect.
[image]

But my layout is long, and I need to scroll to view with an error.
Code:

```
protected void showInputError(TextInputEditText edtText, @StringRes int resId) {
    edtText.setError(getString(resId));
    scrollView.post(() -> {
        scrollView.scrollTo(0, edtText.getTop());
    });
}
```

All works fine first time. But the app does the same scrolling after any other scrolling. 
I mean,

1. set an error to view
2. scroll programmatically to this view
3. scroll manually to another place. Application scrolls again to view from step 2.

The main problem: **Application scrolls back to view when user scrolls manually (after applying of scrollTo)**

Please, give a hint how to overcome this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to a specific view in scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483188/scroll-to-a-specific-view-in-scroll-view)

Comment: @krishankTripathi I know how to scroll in code. But the main problem is that "Application scrolls back to view when user scrolls manually (after applying of scrollTo)"