# PopupWindow overlaps ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, popup, popupwindow

I am using PopupWindow for show validation error with showAsDropDown(anchor).Validation Fields are validated by pressing the save button, so If anchor place under action bar, its popup overlaps actionBar. How do I fix this?

[image: Example]

```
 protected void showPopup(View anchorPlace) {
    popupContainer.removeAllViews();
    popupContainer.addView(recyclerErrors);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        popupContainer.setElevation(0);
        anchorPlace.setElevation(0);
        popup.setElevation(0);
    }
    recyclerErrors.setOnClickListener(v -> dismissPopup());
    popup.setContentView(popupContainer);
    if (anchorPlace != null) {
        popup.setWidth(anchorPlace.getWidth());
    }
    popup.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popup.setFocusable(false);
    popup.setTouchable(true);
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

    if (anchorPlace != null) {
        PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(popup, anchorPlace, 0, 0, Gravity.BOTTOM);
    }

    if (popup.isAboveAnchor()) {
        popup.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Popup for validation error XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/warning_triangle" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/error_field_error_txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/warning_bcg"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_warning"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/settings_error_body_padding_top_bottom"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/settings_error_body_padding_start_end"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/settings_error_body_padding_top_bottom"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/settings_error_body_padding_start_end"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/settings_error_body_padding_top_bottom"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/settings_error_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add the xml code

Comment: `ActionBar` isn't overlapping content. But popup with text "The attribute must be valid.." is overlapping all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `editText.requestFocus()` before calling `showPopup(...)` and do let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Try `popup.setAttachedInDecor(true)`

> This will attach the popup window to the decor frame of the parent window to avoid overlaping with screen decorations like the navigation bar.

Also you may try using `popup.setOverlapAnchor(false)`

> Sets whether the popup window should overlap its anchor view when displayed as a drop-down.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

try to subtract both action and status bar height :

```
popup.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT - actionBarHeight - statusBarHeight);
```

my case, i created popupwindow programmatically with a FrameLayout parent.

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(frameLayout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT - actionBarHeight - statusBarHeight);
```

Comment: this case will not solve the problem if  a navigation drawer is open

Answer (score 1):

Try these !

1st hide keyboard, so the top content will be visible.

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard(View view){
  InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Then if you are using scrollview scroll to where (EditText/Other View) you want to show popup !

```
View targetView = findViewById(R.id.DESIRED_VIEW_ID);  
targetView.getParent().requestChildFocus(targetView,targetView);
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31764551/5557479

or another ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35627860/5557479

Comment: There are a lot of edittexts on the screen, so hiding the keyboard won't solve this problem

Comment: Then 1st scroll to where to view popup then display popup !